# Почему не получается изменить кодировку текста?

Tags: кодировка, vbscript, перекодировка, wsh

На просторах Интернета нашёл VBS скрипт, который должен менять кодировку текста:

```
Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
stream.Type = 2
stream.Charset = "windows-1251"
stream.Open()
stream.LoadFromFile("G:\sourceFile.txt")
Text = stream.ReadText()
stream.Close()

stream.Charset = "windows-1256"
stream.Open()
stream.WriteText(Text)
stream.SaveToFile "G:\resultFile.txt", 2
stream.Close()
```

Но при попытке перекодировать текст

> Привет, я Дима!

из Windows-1251 в Windows-1256 (арабские символы) он выводит

> ?»??????????µ?‚, ?? ?”?????°!

И это совсем не похоже на арабские символы. Подскажите, в чём загвоздка и как решить задачу?

Comment: Вы в программе, которой открываете результат, указали новую кодировку? Не удивительно что она показывает каракули при считывании w1256, если ожидает w1251.

Comment: Да, указывал. Пробовал открывать готовый resultFile в Sublime Text и Notepad++ с нужной мне арабской кодировкой. Но всё те же знаки вопроса.

Comment: Хорошо, а как по-вашему кириллические символы должны превратиться в арабские? Текст ведь тоже должен быть на арабском.

Comment: Попробуйте перекодировать вот это "تسجّل الآن لحضور" из utf-8 в windows-1256.

Comment: А ещё лучше используйте utf-8 для всех языков. Windows ненужон 